# Is there a minor-mode which colors html color codes?

Tags: emacs

I'm looking for an emacs minor mode that colors html color codes, e.g. `#D6199F` in its corresponding color. Apparently https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode does that, but not as a separate minor-mode. Is such a minor-mode around?

Comment: In addition, you may like to see a list of colors that the current display can handle with `M-x list-colors-display` (in emacs).

Comment: kewl question. Never thought of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [rainbow-mode](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/rainbow-mode.html). It is installable through GNU ELPA.